# jQuery multiple parallax buttons

Tags: javascript, jquery, parallax

I've got a bunch of divs on a single page that are all of the same type to be used as buttons. They all currently have the same class `box`, each with it's own unique content.

I'm trying to get them to move away from the mouse ever so slightly to create a slight parallax effect. But I'm having trouble making them move independently from each other.

Currently, this is what I've tried:

```
$(function() {
    $('.box').each(function() {
        var location = $(this).offset();
        var locationX = location.left;
        var locationY = location.top;

        $('html').on("mousemove", function(event) {
            var offsetX = (locationX - event.pageX) / 100;
            var offsetY = (locationY - event.pageY) / 100;

            $('.box').css('transform', 'translate3d(' + offsetX + 'px, ' + offsetY + 'px, 0)');
        });
    });
});
```

So basically, I grab the location of each box element to which I get it's X and Y position. Then the event is supposed to get the cursor's position then do some math to generate the parallax effect based on the *initial* position of the box.

Now I know why this doesn't work, because on the line with the css, I'm using `.box` which applies to every box element on the page to position of the last declared box. My original intention was to use `this` in it's place, but it then refers to `html` which is used when starting the `mousemove` function, but I really want to access the instance of `box` just above it.

What do I need to do to make the boxes move independently from each other?

([Here's a jfiddle of what I've got so far](https://jsfiddle.net/w3j69khd/))

Comment: So when you `hover` on box, you want to move it right?

Comment: @GuruprasadRao When I hover anywhere on the page

Comment: The jfiddle would work perfectly if it was a single box on the screen. But when you have more than one, they all moved as if they're all locked together. But I rather that they move independently.

Comment: So there must be some `page offset` based on which you want to decide which `.box` to move.. Is it something like that? Its quite confusing..

Comment: @GuruprasadRao Yeah that's already in the code; `offsetX` and `offsetY`. Which is then being applied using css and `translate3d` to alter them from their original positions. The problem is I can't apply each individual offset to each individual box (as declared using `.each()` at the top) because the offset will always be applied to all boxes, because the css is referring to `.box`. Ideally I would have replaced that with `this` had it not been wrapped around a `html` element for use with `"mousemove"` so I can't access the individual box to apply the offset to.

Comment: Like I said, everything would work perfectly had it been a single box on the screen, but with multiple boxes, I can't apply the correct offset to the correct instance of a box. It applies to all of them instead.

Comment: How about placing `.each` inside `html mousemove event`? **[`Well I had it but I don't see any difference`](https://jsfiddle.net/Guruprasad_Rao/w3j69khd/6/)**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This script moves the boxes independently but the amount of independent movement is small (see below).

jQuery

```
  $('html').on("mousemove", function(event) {
    var mouseX = event.pageX;
    var mouseY = event.pageY;

    $('.box').each(function( i ) {
      var location = $(this).offset();
      var locationX = location.left;
      var locationY = location.top;
      var offsetY = ( locationY - mouseY ) / 40;
      var offsetX = ( locationX - mouseX ) / 30;
      //console.log( i + ' locationX: ' + locationX );
      $( this ).css('transform', 'translate3d(' + offsetX + 'px, ' + offsetY + 'px, 0)');

  });
});
```

Rendered html from devtools:

```
<body translate="no">

    <div class="box" style="top: 50px; left: 50px; transform: translate3d(-27.3027px, -0.854667px, 0px);">
      Box 1
    </div>

    <div class="box" style="top: 50px; left: 250px; transform: translate3d(-23.2213px, -0.854667px, 0px);">
  Box 2
</div>

<div class="box" style="top: 50px; left: 450px; transform: translate3d(-19.1397px, -0.854667px, 0px);">
  Box 3
</div>
</body>
```

So maybe re-calculating the parallax math? That is, since the boxes are aligned vertically they will always have the same offsetY and so will never move relative to each other in that dimension. Their locationX differs by 200px and if you divide that by 50 they can only move 4px relative to each other. I think your offset calculation needs more complexity.

Codepen: http://codepen.io/SteveClason/pen/JKjWVB?editors=1111

Comment: I see what you mean. Any idea on how to add more complexity?

Comment: It depends on the look you are trying to achieve, but there are many options. The `each` function is indexed so you might use that, like `var offsetY = ( locationY - mouseY ) / ( i * 40);` (I have no idea what that would look like, it's just a code sample). Or you might emphasize in the translation the original location, like `var offsetY = ( (locationY * 2) - mouseY ) / 40;'. I don't know what that would like either but I'm pretty sure it would be ugly. I suggest goofing around on your jfiddle.